# How to fetch the N(th) column from a csv in spark using only rdd, not dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I want to select a column from a csv file using only rdd function, not dataframe in spark. I have written code for it.

Some of the other columns have an empty value.

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(filename)    
rdd_parc = rdd.map(lambda x: x.split(","))
rdd1 = rdd_parc.map(lambda x: x[6] != "")
```

But this solution seems that it will not select the column 6 but it instead selects the element 6 of the map.

Sample data:

```
Lachine,H,0,,,,"SUMMERLEA, PARC",FR,2016,287826.19201900001,5033164.33193000030,-73.7169573579999,45.4382054
Lachine,H,0,,,,"SUMMERLEA, PARC",FR,2016,287826.19201900001,5033164.33193000030,-73.7169573579999,45.4382054
```

You can see that some values are empty.
I want my answer to be

```
SUMMERLEA, PARC
SUMMERLEA, PARC
```

Comment: By "select a column", do you mean you want `rdd1` to only have the sixth column? You also say "it will not select the *row* 6". Do you mean column or row?

Comment: Yes rdd to have only 6th column. But it is not selecting the column. ISorry its a typo in question.

Comment: Try `rdd1 = rdd_parc.map(lambda x: x[6])`.

Comment: Tried the above solution but it only returns the letter at 6th position not the 6th column.

Comment: There are two problems here. 1. You have to deal with quoted strings that may contain `,` as part of the data. 2. Second lambda maps to `True`/`False`. I guess you wanted to use `.filter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done try using to to convert to rdd first by

```
rdd = spark.read.csv(filename, header=True).rdd
```

Then extract the sixth column by

```
rdd_parc = rdd.map(lambda x: x[6])
```

You will get the desired output